# Prove the sum of two different linear transformations is a linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra

How to prove that the sum of two different linear transformation is a linear transformation? I'm not too sure if I should use the properties of linear transformation to prove it?

I know that I have to end up with
(f1+f2)(x + y) = (f1+f2)(x) + (f1+f2)(y)
and
c(f1+f2)(x) = (f1 + f2)(cx)

but Im not too sure how to go between the begin and end statements.

Comment: Start by applying the definition of the sum of linear transformations. That is: what does $(f_1+f_2)(\dots)$ mean?

Comment: Per the comment of @Karl you might start with [Linear Map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_map) : at the very start of the "Definition and first consequences" section.  Note that there are two constraints on the function $f$ that make it a linear map.  All that you have to do is demonstrate algebraically, that if the functions $f$ and $g$ each separately satisfy the two constraints, then so does the function $[f + g]$, where $[f+g](u)$ is **by definition** $f(u) + g(u)$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Have a look at [this MathJax guide](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to learn how to make your questions easier to read :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A function $f$ between two vector spaces $V$ and $W$ over the same field $K$ is linear iff $$f(\lambda u+v) = \lambda f(u) + f(v)$$ holds for each $u,v\in V$ and $\lambda\in K$.

So let $g$ and $h$ be two linear functions and let $u,v\in V$ and $\lambda\in K$. Then for the sum $f = g+h$, $$ f(\lambda u + v) = (g+h)(\lambda u + v) = g(\lambda u + v) + h(\lambda u+v)$$
using the definition of a sum of functions. Since $g$ and $h$ are by assumption both linear, $g(\lambda u +v) = \lambda g(u) + g(v)$ and $h(\lambda v + u) = \lambda h(v) + h(u)$. Thus,
$$g(\lambda u + v) + h(\lambda u+v) = \lambda g(u) + g(v) + \lambda h(u) + h(v) = \lambda g(u) + \lambda h(u) + g(v) + h(u)$$
Now apply again the definition of a sum of functions: $$\lambda g(u) + g(v) + \lambda h(u) + h(v) = \lambda g(u) + \lambda h(u) + g(v) + h(u) = \lambda (g + h)(u) + (g + h)(v) = \lambda f(u) + f(v)$$
and we are done.